# TabIndex property is not working in Windows Phone 8 application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am setting the TabIndex propertry inside the Grid.
My code is `

```
        <Grid Margin="30,12" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="White">
            <TextBlock  Foreground="#FF858585" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Password, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" 
              Padding="10,8"  x:Name="tb_pwd" />
            <PasswordBox TabIndex="1" Password=""  Background="Transparent"  BorderBrush="#FF1ba1e2"
                        Style="{StaticResource PwdBoxStyle}" Grid.Row="1" MaxLength="15" GotFocus="txtpwd_GotFocus_1" LostFocus="txtpwd_LostFocus_1" x:Name="txtpwd">
            </PasswordBox>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  Margin="30,0" Background="White">
            <TextBlock  Foreground="#FF858585" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Domain, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" 
                        Padding="10,8"  x:Name="tb_domain" />
            <TextBox TabIndex="2"  Text="" Background="Transparent"  BorderBrush="#FF1ba1e2"   
                      Style="{StaticResource TxtBoxStyle}" 
                      Grid.Row="2" GotFocus="txtdomain_GotFocus_1"
                      LostFocus="txtdomain_LostFocus_1" 
                      Grid.Column="1" x:Name="txtdomain" MaxLength="15" />
        </Grid>`
```

But in emulator when i write username and click tab it does not work. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you expect the end user will press Tab on his Windows Phone device? I guess tab-index navigation just doesn't work as it doesn't make sense in Mobile world.

Comment: ur words make sense. actually i was building app in windows 8, while doing testing i required it.

Answer (score 1):

The SIP (keyboard) on windows phone does not include a tab key and so there is not support internally for this.

The de-facto convention in apps is to advance the tab focus from code when the user presses the enter key.
There are lots of resources online that show how to do this and helper classes to make it really simple.